# Clarification versus assent

Tags: parentheticals

If person A says, “A hymn is a way to show devotion.” And person B added, “ to a deity.”
So that the sentence is: A hymn is a way to show devotion [to a deity]

Is it correct to say that person B is adding a parenthetical for clarification? Or is person B providing assent to person A’s statement? Or can we not tell what person B’s intent was when he said “to a deity”?

Comment: If that’s all the context we get, then it is impossible to say why person B felt the need to add on.  It seems reasonable that it would be for clarification because hymns are not written or sung about girlfriends even though one might be devoted to them.

Comment: Thank you, I think that without any additional words we cannot tell what person B meant with theses  words alone -“to a deity”

Comment: I would take that as B agreeing that the statement is true if the clarification is included. You could take it as B correcting A.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Or indeed ***clarifying***...

Comment: Person B is adding (what they regard as) a necessary caveat, from a communications perspective.  With the two utterances, A makes a statement using a declarative sentence. B tags on a semi-corrective / mitigating modifier, using a sentence fragment.